# Android / iOS / JSON advice needed

Tags: c#, android, ios, json, t-sql

Advice needed, please!

I am about to start writing a C# Web Forms application that will utimately store forms data (i.e. Textbox, dropdown list and values, their position in the form, default values etc) in JSON format within an SQL database. This JSON data will then be called via an API by an app (Android / iOS) and then render said JSON into a form onto the device, in order for the user to complete. They will then submit this completed form via another API endpoint and it will be stored within the database.

So,

1) Will this work? I am very unfamiliar with JSON, iOS and Android development
2) Is there a better way of doing this?

Any advice appreciated!

Adam

Answer (score 2):

Adam Parker,

I believe you have completely misunderstood the concept of JSON,API and mobile platforms like android and ios :)

*I am very unfamiliar with JSON*

You must understand JSON is not a technology in itself. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

It is just another way to represent data in a key-value pair. What makes JSON so speacial is that it is very easy to create it by machines and it is very easy to read them not just by machienes but by humans as well :)

JSON is language and platform independent :)

Lemme give an example :)

```
{
    "name": "Adam Parker",
    "age": 25
}
```

The above is a valid JSON. Now in that name and age are keys :) now value for key name is Adam Parker and value for key age is 25.

Now no matter in what language I generate this JSON may it be JAVA,Objective C or Android it will always be the same.

*Data will be saved in JSON format within an SQL database*

You must understand JSON is not one of the premitive data type supported by most of the relative data bases like mySQL.

If you be stubborn about saving the JSON in RDBMS then you will be forced to save JSON String in one of the table column. Clearly one of the worst way to do it if you ask me.

JSON Should be constructed on the fly by the server (API) by accessing the individual fields of Database table.

Example : Lets assume I have a database table called users that has two columns name and age.

```
        name           |  age
        Adam Parker       25
```

Now in order to construct the above JSON Ill read name and age fileds of table users and construct JSON depending on which language am using :)

for example in JAVA

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "Adam Parker");
obj.put("age", new Integer(25));
```

Don't assume that this is a JAVA JSON object so will not be understood by anyother language. If you print the description of obj you will see the plain JSON which is same for all platforms :)

*Will this work?*

Yes it will. Thats the purpose of writing API's. API's are meant for providing the communication between the two devices preferrably called as Server and Client.

These Server and Client may or may not be on same platform.So API's intended for cross platform inter-opearbility :)

Now these API's should be able to communicate between two devices of differrent platform so they must use the commonly known data representations and JSON is one such representation tahts all :)

You might conside using XML as well :)

*I am very unfamiliar with iOS and Android development*

If you are just an API developer you need not be aware of any other platform then the one you use to develop the API itself in your case C#.

*Is there a better way of doing this?*

May be if you can figure out much globally accepted,admired data representation format then JSON and XML :)

Hope I made my point clear :) Hapy coding buddy :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response!

So, if I'm storing in a database, perhaps the best method would be to have a "Forms" table and a "FormFields" table on a 1:Many relationship, then, build the structure on the fly from that?

The ideal endpoint is that we add a form and its fields, default values, position (etc) into a database and then the fields can be dynamically rendered by an app on a mobile device. Knowing little of Android / iOS development - I was hoping someone could clarify whether receiving JSON (or XML as you've mentioned) would be enough to do this?

Comment: Yes :) each form will have form fields so the data of these form fields will be rendered dynamically by the mobile devices :) for each for field the value should be provided by your endpoint API either in the form of JSON OR XML. I din get you what do u mean by form table and form field table ??? Is each form an entity in data base for you??? If yes then your approach is correct. Please design your RDBMS scheme before jumping onto the development of API itself.

Comment: Lemme explain :) see in the above example user is an entity in dB not the registration form containing username and age :) form usually renders the form fields and these form fields values are inserted to dB so for the above table one form might contain name and age as it's form fields but that form itself is not an entity in db.entities can be assumed as real world objects like user form is not a real world entity. If u still din get it I strongly recommend you to read the fundamentals of RDBMS schema design and normalization before jumping to development of API :)